# Distrubution Upgrade (18.04 -> 20.04) stuck

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 off a DVD last night.

I added a few basics like gcc, make, build-essential, manpages-dev, dkms, git, a wifi driver (using dkms), curl, gnupg, brave-browser, and Steam.  Then today tried to upgrade the OS to version 20.04 via the Software Updater GUI.  It got as far as "Installing the Upgrades"

"Focal" window says:
`Unpacking libselinux1 (amd64)`

and in the terminal below:

````
Preparing to unpack .../libpam0g_1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam0g:amd64 (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1) over (1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libpam0g:amd64 (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1) ...
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf", line 10: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...Checking init scripts...```

var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log: 

```2021-01-12 14:37:10,612 DEBUG demoted: 'libdbusmenu-gtk4 libegl1-mesa libllvm6.0'
2021-01-12 14:37:10,612 DEBUG found components: {'focal': {'main', 'universe', 'restricted', 'multiverse'}, 'focal-updates': {'main', 'universe', 'restricted', 'multiverse'}, 'focal-security': {'main', 'universe', 'restricted', 'multiverse'}}
2021-01-12 14:37:10,616 DEBUG quirks: running StartUpgrade
2021-01-12 14:37:10,616 DEBUG running Quirks.StartUpgrade
2021-01-12 14:37:10,616 DEBUG skipping 'README' (no '.')
2021-01-12 14:37:10,616 DEBUG killing update-notifier
2021-01-12 14:37:10,633 DEBUG killing kblueplugd kbluetooth4
2021-01-12 14:37:10,651 DEBUG killing gnome-screensaver
2021-01-12 14:37:10,671 DEBUG setup poke timer for the screensaver
2021-01-12 14:37:10,684 INFO cache.commit()
2021-01-12 14:44:09,474 WARNING no activity on terminal for 300 seconds (Unpacking libselinux1 (amd64))
````

There's this window off the to side named "Frontend" that says "Configuring libpamOg:amd64" and has a checkbox that says "Restart services during package upgrades without asking?"  Toggling it  does nothing.

I can't open the "Files" app nor the System Settings app.

What should I do now?

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your releases are your usage of *yy* based releases implies *snap* only Ubuntu releases, but your tag & description don't match that.

Comment: Installing an older release only to attempt to immediately upgrade to a new release is not a good plan.  I suggest that you just install 20.04 cleanly.  See: Create a bootable USB stick on [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) / [Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) | [Install Ubuntu desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Sorry, that was lazy of me.  It was 18.04 to 20.04.

Comment: Please correct your question (you can edit your own questions), then I can remove my comment.  Ubuntu has both *yy.mm* products, and since 2016 *yy* products (they are different systems, *yy* releases have 10 years of support without need of ESM, use *snaps* only etc).  Mixing two different products because of laziness can lead to wrong details (*it's better if we're not forced to make assumptions as to what you mean*).

Comment: I tried "dpkg --configure -a" and it complained about something being locked.  So I tried killing the update window with ctrl+C and it wouldn't die.  I tried restarting from the OS menu and it hung on restart.  So I finally did a hardware reset.  And now it won't boot.  It says on loading, "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occured and the system can't  recover.  Please log out and try again."  So I guess I'll start over with a 20.04 install.   If I got stuck on an upgrade after 1 day of  use, what chance does anyone else have?